# <p:dataTable>'s onExpandStart attribute is not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, datatable

In my application I want to execute a client side method before expanding row of `<p:dataTable>` so I am using `onExpandStart="alert('Helo');"`. But this also is not working for me.

.xhtml code snippet :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{ExampleDataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" onExpandStart="alert('Helo');">
    <p:column id="rowToggle" styleClass="rowtoggle">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
          ..........
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

can anyone tell wher I have done wrong? I am using PF 3.4,Mojara(2). Thanks.

**Update-1 :**
  managedBean's code snippet :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "columnController")
@ViewScoped
public class ColumnController implements Serializable {
private List<ColumnDTO> userNames;


public List<ColumnDTO> getUserNames() {
    List<ColumnDTO> columns = new ArrayList<ColumnDTO>();
    columns.add(new ColumnDTO(Integer.valueOf(1), "Diganta"));
    columns.add(new ColumnDTO(Integer.valueOf(2), "Jayanta"));
    columns.add(new ColumnDTO(Integer.valueOf(3), "Proloy"));

    return columns;
}
public void setUserNames(List<ColumnDTO> userNames) {
    this.userNames = userNames;
}
}
```

ColumnDTO.java :

```
public class ColumnDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4828438441215128064L;

private Integer columnId;
private String columnName;

public ColumnDTO(Integer index, String columnName) {
    this.columnId = index;
    this.columnName = columnName;
}
    //...........getter setter
   }
```

**.xhtml code** :

```
<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<h:form>
<p:dataTable value="#{columnController.userNames}" var="name" onExpandStart="alert('Hello')">
    <p:column>
        <p:rowToggler/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{name.columnName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <h:outputText value="#{name.columnId}" />
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have datatable inside form?>

Comment: @Makky :yes datatable is inside `<h:form>`.

Comment: Post full code including your backbean.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<p:ajax event="rowToggle" onstart="alert('Helo');"/>` instead of `onExpandStart`

Comment: Thanks for reply @ Balibia, I already tried this but it is called both for row collapse and expand. I need only for rowExpand.